# Updating UI from webview's Javascript Interface crashes the app

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm working on a hybrid webview/native app and am running into an issue where the app crashes.

Here's the quick rundown:

- app is in a single FrameLayout
- the top has a LinearLayout where I place a button to on the left & right sides and my app's logo in the middle & below that I have my WebView
- I'm using `webview.addJavascriptInterface(myObj, "myJsName")` to attach a JS interface to the web view
- in the webView I load a simple HTML page that calls public methods in my JS interface. These methods just show or hide the various View in the faux "title bar" (the LineadLayout)
- the methods in my JS interface are called just fine - but if i try to update the UI in those calls the app crashes with a `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)`

Here's the relevant code from my activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

    javascriptInterface = new JavascriptInterface() {
        public void showLogo() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    MyActivity.this.logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }

        public void hideLogo() {
            MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    MyActivity.this.logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(javascriptInterface, JavascriptInterface.NAME);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
}
```

- When calling `hideLogo()` from my JS code the app crashes with `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)`.
- if i remove the `MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread` and just try to modify the UI nothing happens (no crash either)
- when debugging I have assured that the `logo` variable is not null and indeed represents the  correct ImageView
- also, upon calling `hideLogo()` the logo does disappear right before the app crashes

So, now I'm really confused. I've tried using a `Handler` and an `AsycTask` & both give me the same type of crash.

I'm super new to Android so I'm hoping I'm doing something stupid here. Any and all help is appreciated!

*update here's verbose output from log cat*

```
10-01 12:29:55.591: INFO/Choreographer(10074): Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-01 12:29:55.622: null/libc(10074): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 10074 (com.arin.test)
10-01 12:29:55.724: INFO/DEBUG(121): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-01 12:29:55.724: INFO/DEBUG(121): Build fingerprint: 'google/takju/maguro:4.1.1/JRO03C/398337:user/release-keys'
10-01 12:29:55.724: INFO/DEBUG(121): pid: 10074, tid: 10074, name: com.arin.test  >>> com.arin.test <<<
10-01 12:29:55.724: INFO/DEBUG(121): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000008
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): r0 00000008  r1 5bc3ebc0  r2 00000010  r3 00000004
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): r4 5a52d008  r5 5a52de38  r6 00000001  r7 00000004
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): r8 00000008  r9 00000001  sl 00000004  fp 00000001
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): ip 00000001  sp bedb2310  lr 5bea188c  pc 5beca774  cpsr 80000010
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d0  00000000bd0d3d00  d1  3f8469ee00000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d2  0000000000000080  d3  000000000000003f
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d4  0000000000000000  d5  000000003f800000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d6  3f8469eebd0d3dcb  d7  3f8000003f800000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d8  bf800000bf800000  d9  0000000000000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d16 0000000000000008  d17 000000c1417d8568
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d18 000000000358b208  d19 0000000000000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d24 3fee45a1e2e00000  d25 4000000006800000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d28 408d900000000000  d29 0000000000000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): d30 bffffffff8a00000  d31 0000000000000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): scr 20000010
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): backtrace:
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): #00  pc 00034774  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): #01  pc 0000b888  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): stack:
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22d0  03d00000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22d4  00000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22d8  5a4defc8
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22dc  5a5316c0
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22e0  5a52dee4
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22e4  00000008
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22e8  00000002
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22ec  00000004
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22f0  5a52dee4
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22f4  5a52d008
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22f8  5a52de34
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22fc  00000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2300  00000004
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2304  00000023
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2308  df0027ad
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb230c  00000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): #00  bedb2310  5a52d008
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): ........  ........
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): #01  bedb2310  5a52d008
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2314  5bea188c  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2318  5a52d008
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb231c  00000004
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2320  00000004
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2324  00000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2328  00000005
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb232c  5bea398c  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2330  5a52d008
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2334  00000004
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2338  00000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb233c  5bef106c  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2340  00000005
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2344  5bea4a70  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so (glDrawArrays+804)
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2348  00000004
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb234c  00000000
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): memory near r1:
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5bc3eba0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5bc3ebb0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5bc3ebc0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5bc3ebd0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5bc3ebe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): memory near r4:
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5a52cfe8 5a525fe0 00000001 00000000 00000007  ._RZ............
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5a52cff8 00000007 00000007 00000000 00000f9b  ................
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5a52d008 00000018 0000e7f4 00001c80 00001100  ................
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5a52d018 00001100 0000000a 00000428 00000048  ........(...H...
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5a52d028 0000003c 00000048 0000003c 00000004  <...H...<.......
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): memory near r5:
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5a52de18 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5a52de28 00000000 00000000 5a52dc0c 5a52dcb4  ..........RZ..RZ
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5a52de38 5a52dce4 00000000 00000000 00000000  ..RZ............
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5a52de48 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5a52de58 00000002 00000003 00000003 00000004  ................
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): memory near sp:
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb22f0 5a52dee4 5a52d008 5a52de34 00000000  ..RZ..RZ4.RZ....
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2300 00000004 00000023 df0027ad 00000000  ....#....'......
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2310 5a52d008 5bea188c 5a52d008 00000004  ..RZ...[..RZ....
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2320 00000004 00000000 00000005 5bea398c  .............9.[
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): bedb2330 5a52d008 00000004 00000000 5bef106c  ..RZ........l..[
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): code around pc:
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5beca754 e781410c e28cc001 e15c0003 3afffffa  .A........\....:
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5beca764 e8bd8010 e92d4010 e3a0c000 ea000004  .....@-.........
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5beca774 e5904000 e5014008 e5904004 e0800002  .@...@...@......
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5beca784 e5014004 e15c0003 e2811008 e28cc001  .@....\.........
10-01 12:29:55.849: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5beca794 3afffff6 e8bd8010 e92d4010 e3a0c000  ...:.....@-.....
10-01 12:29:55.856: INFO/DEBUG(121): code around lr:
10-01 12:29:55.856: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5bea186c e3530000 1a000005 e1a03007 e59c0018  ..S......0......
10-01 12:29:55.856: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5bea187c e59c101c e59c2014 e1a0e00f e59cf024  ..... ......$...
10-01 12:29:55.856: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5bea188c e2866001 e2855004 e5942e50 e3a03001  .`...P..P....0..
10-01 12:29:55.856: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5bea189c e1560002 3affffeb e2840eed e1a01008  ..V....:........
10-01 12:29:55.856: INFO/DEBUG(121): 5bea18ac e280000c e1a02003 e8bd41f0 eaffe178  ..... ...A..x...
10-01 12:29:56.060: INFO/WindowState(321): WIN DEATH: Window{425993f8 com.arin.test/com.arin.test paused=false}
10-01 12:29:56.060: INFO/ActivityManager(321): Process com.arin.test (pid 10074) has died.
10-01 12:29:56.060: WARN/ActivityManager(321): Force removing ActivityRecord{4226e5d0 com.arin.test/com.arin.test}: app died, no saved state
10-01 12:29:56.099: DEBUG/Zygote(124): Process 10074 terminated by signal (11)
10-01 12:29:56.161: WARN/InputMethodManagerService(321): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 10074 uid 10008
```

Comment: what error is shown in your logcat when the app crashes?

Comment: updated with verbose output from logcat. there's no java stacktrace tho

Comment: You seem to be seeing an instance of http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35288

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. Using a Handler fixed it:

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface   
    {  
        // gets called from JavasScript
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")  
        public void notifyStarted()  
        {  
            _handler.post(_onNavigationStarted);
        }  
    } 

    final Handler _handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable _onNavigationStarted = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            _me.navigationStarted();
        }
    };

    protected void navigationStarted() {
        _btnNavigate.setEnabled(true);
        _btnNavigate.setText(_me.getResources().getString(R.string.Navigate));
    }
```

Comment: When you trigger a UI change from javascript, javascript page crashes. You need to use a handler as Abdo did.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use.  Here's a simple example that will display a `Toast`.  Try this and see if it works.

In your `onCreate()`:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.addJavascriptInterface( new JavascriptInterface(), "Android" );
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

Your `JavascriptInterface` (Defined inside the `Activity` that uses it):

```
private class JavascriptInterface {

    public void makeToast( String toastText ) {

        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}
```

In your javascript:

```
function makeToast() {

    Android.makeToast("Test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. I don't know how or why this was happening - but a different approach solved the issue:

- i was using a single view xml file (`main.xml`). the top 45dp of the view was dedicated to a RelativeLayout that emulated a title bar and the rest was a WebView
- I moved all the faux title bar elements out of `main.xml` and created a custom title bar (`title.xml`). this solved my problem

I have no idea why it was breaking to begin with but now it works and I can move on with my life.

Another things worth noting was that while debugging I added a bunch of native controls that made the same calls that the HTML buttons were calling via the JS interface & that worked 100% well.

The initial approach let to crazy memory access violations every time I tried to modify view properties via the JS interface.